# Deuteronomy 32:14 "fattened lambs" or "fat of lambs"?

Tags: deuteronomy

Deuteronomy 32:14
New International Version

> with curds and milk from herd and flock and with **fattened lambs and goats**, with choice rams of Bashan and the finest kernels of wheat. You drank the foaming blood of the grape.

English Standard Version

> Curds from the herd, and milk from the flock, with **fat of lambs, rams** of Bashan and goats, with the very finest of the wheat— and you drank foaming wine made from the blood of the grape.

Which version is more accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deut 32:14 is a tricky verse to translate.  Let me try to convey some of the difficulties.  I would translate this verse overly literally as follows:

> Curds from the cattle
>
> And **milk** of the flock
>
> with **fat** of lambs
>
> And rams of the breed of Bashan
>
> And goats with the **fat** kidneys wheat
>
> And the blood of of the grapes you drank wine

Note that all the highlighted words are the same word but pointed differently by the (uninspired) Masoretes.  That word is "HLV"; when pointed as חָלָב it is "milk"; but when pointed as חֶלֶב it is "fat" or "oil".  Thus, "fat of lambs" could quite easily be, "milk of lambs".  This might be preferable in view of the Torah's prohibition against eating animal fat Lev 3:17, 7:22-25.  However some versions may have it idiomatically correct by saying, "fatted lambs" meaning large lambs.

In any case, the overall image of V13 and V14 is one of a people living on the very best of the land and living on the very best/finest of food.

Further, "kidneys" in this instance stands for something else.  Most modern versions translate this verse idiomatically to say something like:

> with curds from cattle and milk from the flock, and with fattened lambs and
> goats, with choice rams of Bashan and the finest kernels of wheat. You
> drank the choicest blood of the grape.

**CONCLUSION**

By questioning the Masoretic pointing it is possible to get a slightly different meaning; but the idiomatic meaning is a land producing plenty of good food.  This is similar to the well-known idiom of a "land flowing with milk and honey", which is clearly not literal but idiom for a land with plenty of good, choicest food.